# mylivechat click even javascript

Tags: javascript, events, click, addeventlistener

I've created this to demonstrate my problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/nwo2oxqc/

Basically, I'm trying to use querySelector on a div that opens a popup, so that I can detect when it is clicked.

However, the error is shown:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

So for some reason, the querySelector cannot find that element.

Is this because the mylivechat js script is not fully loaded yet? Is there something I need to do to wait until the script is loaded?

Comment: Yes, it's in fact due to mylivechat is not being fully loaded yet. You need to find a way to figure out when it's done

Comment: As, your chat is in iframe. Due to which you cannot access elements inside it. That's why you are not able to capture click events on it.

Comment: But I get exactly the same problem on my site which doesnt have iframe Bilal, so I dont think is due to iframe.

Answer (score 0):

You must add the eventListener when the dom is full loaded, if not, the objects won't be present when you add the listener. For this you must encapsulate your function into the clause:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ });
```

Also the class name of the div is "mylivechat_collapsed_text", not "mylivechat_collapsed". If you want capture the click on the arrow, you must add same listener for div with class "mylivechat_sprite"

Solution in this fiddle:
[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vv4jf89c/)

Comment: Thanks Mikel, great answer!

Comment: It is a pleasure to help !, positive feedback is appreciated :)

Comment: Hi Mikel, on further looking at this, it seems to only work inside the jsfiddle example. If I put the basic code in a html page for instance, it doesnt work. I think possible the window.onload function might be the most compatible way to go. Any thoughts?

Comment: You would try put the basic code in an archive.js, maybe don't works into a <script> tag. I would have to research to asert. $(document) is a jQuery function, are you incluiding jQuery library before the <script> definition?? I supose that this can be the cause of the problem because window.onload is a native js event.

Answer (score 0):

Putting inside a window.load function seems to do the trick, so it waits until the page has loaded, then runs the script:

```
    <script>
     window.onload = function () { 
        var myl = document.querySelector('div.mylivechat_collapsed');
        myl.addEventListener('click', function() {
            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'contact', 'livechat', ClientID ]);
        });
        function MyLiveChat_OnInit() {
            MyLiveChat_SetProductName(ClientID);
        }
    }
    </script>
```